# tentative definition has type 'struct drand48_data' that is never completed

Tags: c

I keep getting an error that says my code has tentative definition that is not defined. I do not understand what that means or why I get that error.

Below is the line of code that is causing the error

```
struct drand48_data drand_buf;
```

Then I also have the image of my terminal.

[image: Image of error in terminal / command line]

Comment: 1. Post code as text, not images.  2. you are using names you have not defined, `srand48_r` and `struct drand48_data`.

Answer (score 0):

The types and functions that the error messages are complaining about are declared in stdlib.h which you apparently forgot to include.  You need to add this to the top of your source file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: in ISO C those things must not be defined by `stdlib.h`, so there might be needed some feature test macros or compiler switches

Comment: @M.M The man page lists them as GNU extensions.

Comment: I bet OP is on a mac (using gcc but error message is from clang?), where they're presumably not available.